Is あんまだった some kind of expression?

「俺はひたすら我慢した。道場で必死に素振りなんかしてさ。両親に褒められて、内心苦笑してたりしてたよ。どうにもなってねえってのに」


それで、仕事でアラマツリを斬ってりゃ少しは紛れたか、ってーと…そうだな、俺はあんまだったかな」

The context is the following. The speaking character got asked "Did you suffer from the same disease (that drives people crazy) as your brother and he gives this answer.

「俺はひたすら我慢した。道場で必死に素振りなんかしてさ。両親に褒められて、内心苦笑してたりしてたよ。どうにもなってねえってのに」
-
Here he explains that he endured it. At the dojo the swung is sword desperately. His parents praised him but inside he smiled bitterly. I'm not entirely sure how to take どうにもなってねえってのに here I assume it's akin to どうにもならない. "Despite the fact nothing was good/nothing changed".


それで、仕事でアラマツリを斬ってりゃ少しは紛れたか、ってーと…そうだな、俺はあんまだったかな」

Then he explains that killing アラマツリ on the job may be a good way for him to distract himself. And finally he adds "俺はあんまだったかな"
What exactly is あんまだったhere?

This is あんまりだった with り weakened and skipped. 「仕事でアラマツリを斬ってりゃ少しは紛れたかというと，俺はあんまりだった（「あんまり」だった，＝あんまり紛れなかった）かな」...For me, not really.
